# Emit compilation error for some template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

Consider the following function:

```
template<int N> f()
{
    if(N==5)
    {
        std::cerr << "N=5 is not supported!\n";
        abort();
    }
    do_real_work(N);
}
```

How is it possible to convert the run-time error message into a compile-time error? I guess I could use `static_assert` if I used C++11, but what about C++03?

Comment: Have a look at Boost.StaticAssert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BOOST.StaticAssert`:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(N == 5, "N=5 is not supported!\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to wrap the function in a class template, with partial specializations for the template argument values that aren't supported:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct wrapper {
    static int f() {
        return N;
    }
};

template <>
struct wrapper<5> {
};

int main() {
    std::cout << wrapper<4>::f() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here's how it can be done (basically, without message) in pure C++03 similarly to how it works in boost:

```
template <bool x> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE;

template <> struct STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<true> { enum { value = 1 }; };

template<int n> void f()
{
    sizeof(STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<n==5>);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `? true : false`.

Comment: Don't you also need a return statement in `f`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 surely I did :)